# What Collection should I use in my Adapter for both rows and headers?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `BaseAdapter` that manages the rows in my `ListView`. All this while I've been displaying the records in the listview without any grouping or headers and it has worked fine. My adapter uses an `ArrayList` and for a non-grouped set of data, it works just fine. Here's what it looks like:

```
public class SearchResultsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  public ArrayList<Result> objResults;

  public SearchResultsAdapter(Search ctxContext, ArrayList<Result> objResults) {
    this.objResults = objResults;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
    if (check whether it is a category) {    
      View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.category, null);

      final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
      sectionView.setText("New Category");

      return v;    
    } else {
      View vewRow = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

      TextView tvwName = (TextView) vewRow.findViewById(R.id.name);
      tvwName.setText(objResults.get(position).getName());

      return vewRow;    
    }    
  }

}
```

When the `getView` method of the adapter is invoked internally, it only expects it to return a single row from my collection at that `position`.

Ideally I could has used a `HashMap` as I could have grouped my data and stored the data of each group under a key in the map but I can't reference `HashMap` items by a simple `position` as I can with an `ArrayList`; it's only logical.

I've seen a lot of apps use the `ListView` to show both headers and rows but I haven't understood what collection/pattern is best suited for this.

Thanks.

Comment: [See This Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html)

Comment: this example is bad ... you should override `getViewTypeCount` (and retrun 2) and `getItemViewType` (and return HEADER or ROW(where HEADER and ROW are final static ints) ... in that case you should not get "bad" convertView by "bad" i mean you'll not get convertView which is ROW type for HEADER type item ...

Comment: Hey Samir. Your example was what I was thinking of too. What you did was basically create and an `ArrayList` of a custom `Interface`. Create two classes `Row` and `Section` that implement that custom `Interface` and then when returning the row in the `getView` method of the `BaseAdapter`, return the correct view i.e. row or section based whether the object in the list at that position is a `Row` or a `Section`. This pattern seems to work fine but I was curious whether this is a de-facto pattern for situations like these?! Thanks.

Comment: Hey Samir, if you could post your comment as an answer, I could accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Samir's comment and [example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-sectioned-listview-with-search_6865.html):

Create and an `ArrayList` of a custom Interface. Create two classes - `Row` and `Section` that implement that custom Interface and then when returning the row in the `getView` method of the `BaseAdapter`, return the correct view i.e. row or section based whether the object in the list at that position is a `Row` or a `Section`.